# How to connect to sql database from android in a different network without a web service?

Tags: android, sql

How to connect to SQL database from Android in a different network without a web service? I need a direct connection. Now I am using a jtdc driver, but it is not working if the server and mobile is connected in a different network.

Comment: JDBC is strongly discouraged on mobile and publicly exposed in general. You're going to need a web service... There's really no way around that. Even Firebase works using a web service

Comment: you can't connect from other network and without web server. Your server should be somehow visible to the mobile phone.